# form processing

Tags: php

What I'm trying to do is run a select statement for each answer to select the answer in the database where the questionID = $i and the userID = $userID so I have the query like this set up so far but not sure what I'm missing or am I right and not missing anything? Also no matter what i do both fields have values but I'm still getting the error message that I need to fill out both form fields.

```
<?php 
                    $i = 1;
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                    ?>
                        <dl>

                            <dt style="width: 190px;"><label for="answer[<?php echo $row['id']; ?>]"><?php echo $row['question'] ?></label></dt>
                            <dd><input type="text" name="answer<?php echo $i ?>[<?php echo $row['id']; ?>]" size="54" /></dd>

                        </dl>
                    <?php
                    ++$i;
                    }
                    ?>

    if (empty($_POST['answer1'][$i]) || trim($_POST['answer1'][$i])=="") {$errors = "yes";}
if (empty($_POST['answer2'][$i]) || trim($_POST['answer2'][$i])=="") {$errors = "yes";}

// Error checking, make sure all form fields have input
if ($errors == "yes") {

// Not all fields were entered error
$message = "You must enter values to all of the form fields!";

$output = array('errorsExist' => true, 'message' => $message);

} else {

$userID = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_POST['userID']);
$answer1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_POST['answer1'][$i]);
$answer2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_POST['answer2'][$i]);

$query = "SELECT * FROM manager_users_secretAnswers WHERE questionID = '".$questionID."' AND userID = '".$userID."'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
echo $query;
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you're checking for errors with this:

```
empty($_POST['answer1'][$i]);
```

The problem here is that '$i', in that script, will equal the number of rows in the database +1, since you used it in the while loop. So chances are that will always be empty, and you'll always get the error.

To do that more simply, use a foreach loop for each field (there are many ways to do this, of course):

```
$error = false;
foreach ($_POST['answer1'] as $answer) {
    if ($error === true) break; // we already have an error, why continue?
    if (empty($answer)) $error = true; 
}
```

Before that, and more importantly, your form names appear to be named confusingly.

```
name=answerNUM[ROW_ID]
```

Your result, will be this:

```
answer1[ROW_ID]
answer2[ROW_ID]
answer3[ROW_ID]
answer4[ROW_ID]
//etc...
```

For debugging purposes you will want to dump the POST variable to be able to see the structure of your form when it's submitted:

```
die(print_r($_POST, true));
```

You'll get every value back and be able to compare your code against that. If you want to post the result of that up I can expand on the answer.